# Android MediaPlayer play file while growing (downloading or recording file)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Android MediaPlayer plays a growing file (from local storage /sdcard) considering its duration is whatever the duration was on start. As an example if it downloaded up to 1 minute this will be considered the total duration and even if the file continues to grow, MediaPlayer will stop (OnCompletion) after 1 minute.
How can I make it continue playing?
I tried to setVideoPath again but it repeats from the beginning. Any Help?

Comment: That is a common behavior of players. If you want to stream a file directly let the player load the URL, not the file.

Comment: Streaming is a good solution, but it will not allow me to time shift on the file (rewind and forward)